# How to properly watch scope for data load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've built a custom Angular directive which uses D3.js to build a visualization. I reference this directive in my HTML like so:

```
<gm-link-analysis data="linkAnalysis.connections"></gm-link-analysis>
```

The relevant portion of directive code looks like this:

```
angular.module('gameApp')
  .directive('gmLinkAnalysis', gmLinkAnalysis);

gmLinkAnalysis.$inject = ['$location', 'd3'];

function gmLinkAnalysis($location, d3) {

  var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/app/gmDataVis/gmLinkAnalysis/gmLinkAnalysis.directive.html',
    controller: 'LinkAnalysisController',
    controllerAs: 'linkAnalysis',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.$watch('data', function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        if (json) {
          root = json;
          root.fixed = true;
          root.x = width / 2;
          root.y = height / 2;
          return scope.render(root);
        }
      });

      ...

    }
  };
  return directive;
};
```

...and my controller below:

```
angular.module('gameApp')
  .controller('LinkAnalysisController', LinkAnalysisController);

LinkAnalysisController.$inject = ['$routeParams', 'dataVisService'];

function LinkAnalysisController($routeParams, dataVisService) {
  var vm = this;
  var userId = $routeParams.userId;

  var getConnections = function() {
    dataVisService.getConnections({
      userId: userId
    }).$promise.then(function(connections) {
      vm.connections = connections;
      console.log(vm.connections);
    });
  };

  var init = function() {
    getConnections();
  };

  init();
}
```

It appears that my directive loads before my controller loads the data. I keep seeing `undefined` (from my log within the directive) followed by the data object I'm looking for (from my log within my controller). I understand that the directive would load before my asynchronous API call returns the data in my controller. What I do not understand is why the `$watch` does not pick up on this data when it finally is loaded. How would I go about getting this data into my directive?

Comment: In [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heavyhorse/7983y06k/) that @heavyhorse gave you, the controller was outside the directive. Now you have moved it inside the directive. Are you instantiating the controller twice? Once outside the directive and another inside the directive?

Comment: @georgeawg, I'm only instantiating it once, inside the directive.

Comment: In that case your controller's data is on the isolate scope **inside** the directive and the `data` attribute is connected to something that is undefined. If your controller is **inside** the directive, the controllers data is on the directive's isolate scope as `linkAnalysis`.

Comment: @georgeawg, thanks for leading me down the right road. Using `$scope` rather than the 'controllerAs' syntax solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that your watch is not 'deep' enough. To watch whole object, not simply variable, you can pass third argument `true` to `$watch` function:

```
link: function(scope) {
  scope.$watch('data', function(json) {
    ...
  }, true);
    ...
```

If there is no need to go deep all the way, `$watchCollection` might be used.

More information [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: I believe that in this case `watchCollection` could be applied

Comment: @ Oleg Tikhonov, That is correct, was actually adding that to my post :), thanks

Comment: Unfortunately both `$watch` with the third parameter (`true`) and `$watchCollection` result in `undefined`.

Comment: Using $scope rather than the 'controllerAs' syntax solved my issue, so you were right there was definitely $scope confusion.